# Sub-30second solving the $3\times3\times3$ Rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, speedsolving

I just wanna learn cubing under 30 secs. Please help me:( As i've already learned the Beginner's method. Is there any easiest way to learn the CFOP method as i am unable to understand this method. I learn the Beginner's method by internet and i learned it from a pdf file. It was helpful. Now i can solve a cube in less than 1 min 30 sec.

Once i was in a free mind and tried to solve the cube and i was able to solve the cube in just 31.13 sec. But i'am not able to solve it under 30 sec anymore. Please help me!!!.

If you get any pdf in the internet of the CFOP method then please inform me. 
And yes, I searched it a lot and got many pdf's but can't understand the algorithms and the diagrams. I need a pdf with CFOP tutorial but with the same training animations as in the beginner's method training!!!!!

Comment: Hmm.. there are loads of Beginner's Method PDFs out there (not to mention, there are over 10 different Beginner's Methods out there. All layer-by-layer, but still different techniques, algorithms and orders of solving). So could you perhaps link the Beginner's Method PDF you've used so we know which notation/algorithm/diagrams were easy to understand for you? Also, could you also link some CFOP algorithms and diagrams that are hard to understand so we might be able to help you explain it, or translate the algorithms to make it easier to understand.

Comment: PDFs don't usually have animations…

Answer (score 0):

You can learn Rubik's cube [notation](https://jperm.net/3x3/moves), and practice a lot. Reading in the way most non-cubers understand is very time-consuming and hard to memorize, but you can practice to read this notation with a cube a lot to understand the notation better.

You can always practice solving the cube as fast as possible. In the past, my average of 3x3 is ~1 minute, but I trained a lot and got an average of ~35 seconds, with CFOP with [2-Look OLL](https://jperm.net/algs/2lookoll), while I use 1-Look PLL, but you can do it better.

If solving the cube at that speed is not enough for you, then try learning how to do [fingertricks](https://jperm.net/3x3/fingertricks)  properly, and you can always discover algorithms that you think are good enough to be fast to do.

Answer (score -3):

I say head to http://www.rubiksplace.com/speedcubing/guide/ and learn the 2-look OLL and PLL from there. I found this site really helpful for me and they also tell you what to do after learning the 2-look steps.

The way they teach you to solve:
F2L - They give you som cases and they tell you ways to guide yourself to them.

OLL - They teach you the 2 - look method, or 2 algorithm method, and give you guidance to Full OL just in case you want to be super - fast!

PLL - They teach you how to do 2 - look PLL with simpler algs, so it's easier to learn. They also tell you a bit about Full PLL.

They also give you algorithm sheets for F2L, OLL, and PLL just in case you need them as a cheat sheet.
Overall, this website is one of the best, if not the best, for learning CFOP, and I thoroughly recommend that you use it.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Flaggers: "**[A post should be marked as spam only if it advertises a product, service, or similar and is unsolicited or lacks disclosure.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)**" The question here solicits information on where algorithm diagrams can be found, and this answer appears to provide a site with same, so it is not an ***unsoliticed*** advertisement of a site. It doesn't seem likely that this answerer is directly affiliated with the site in question either, so ***disclosure*** is not at issue.

Comment: @Isaac: With your edit I think this (barely) escapes being a link-only answer. Having said that, you've offered endorsements of this site in a couple of answers now, and I'm making a good faith assumption that you're not doing so because of personal involvement with it. But I'd caution that further promoting of this site, though on topic and well intentioned, will likely draw downvotes because it now looks like your answers are just advertisements.  For this specific question that may be ok, but in general it probably wouldn't be. Maybe you can summarize the *content*, not just give the link?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Thanks. I'll try to in future. 